# How do I access the output on "Lookup Activity" in the Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I'm returning a simple query using Azure Data Factory's `Lookup Activity`.

I'm trying to access the result of that query and then send the result by email.

I'd like to access full output but have failed to do so.

So far, I've tried using the following solutions:

1. `@activity('Lookup1').output` (not sending/receiving email)
2. `@activity('Lookup1').output.count` (works but only returns "2")
3. `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` (returns nothing)

Every time I run this script, it debugs successfully, **I.E:** there is no error message.

This is the output I'm getting:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "value": [
    {
      "company_name": "ABC",
      "folder_name": "Folder1"
    }, {
      "company_name": "DEF",
      "folder_name": "Folder2"
    }
  ],
  "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (Japan East)"
}
```

What I should do to returning full output?

Comment: I already solved it. Actually my output is json object , so all i had to do is convert full output into string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it. Actually my output is json object , so all i had to do is convert full output into string.

Comment: Could you share the details, I am looking for something similar(Fetch data and send in email) and I'm new to ADF? Also, how to ignore the "effectiveIntegrationRuntime" part!

Comment: Can you please share the way you solved it?

Comment: Ravi Raj @string(activity('Lookup1').output)

Answer (score 5):

Here you have to wrap output to string by

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output)
```